# TFS 2013 Delete changesets

Tags: tfs, rollback, destroy

I'm trying to completly delete changesets, say from 110 to 100, like rollback, but don't keep history of changes.
Is it possible? i've tried `tf destroy` but unsuccessfully.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is only possible by destroying all items associated to the ChangeSet including all previous changes made to these items. If you'd `tf destroy` each item in source control you'd be left with just the ChangeSet that created the repository.

You cannot destroy selected changesets if you want to retain a previous version of a file, only roll them back. (or restore a backup of the database containing the ProjectCollection).